# Java process intermittently dying on CentOS 6.4

Tags: java, process, centos, jetty, dropwizard

I run a jar file on a CentOS 6.4 server with this command:

`java -jar service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server myservice-configure.yml &`

However, after a while the process gets killed by itself. I've noticed this happening overnight, 2 hours and 4 to 5 hours.

What are some ways I can troubleshoot for this? The process runs a Jetty server and in the logs I do see this error, however, I'm not sure whether this is the error that's causing the process to get killed. There isn't much traffic for this service at the moment.

I'm the only user of the service sending 4 to 5 requests every hour. The service is accessed over `https` with httpd in front. Not sure if that matters.

```
! java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException: null
! at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:205) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
! at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:402) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.fill(ChannelEndPoint.java:235) ~[service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException` is not a process death, that's a normal I/O read error.   Are there some other logs indicating other problems? or some techniques you've used to verify that the process is dead?

Comment: I've just noticed that sometimes the service starts throwing `503`s and then when I go to the terminal and run `top` I don't see the java process running anymore. That suggests that it died.